# iOS Animation Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, ios-animations

Hopefully someone can help me out. Recently I have been having issues with the animations inside my view. I have been unable to find a solution to it but until now it has been fine as nothing major was going on inside the view, but now I have an alert view showing inside the view after I click a table cell. The alert view comes from the top right hand corner of the screen and goes down the screen and gets bigger with the black background. I just want it to appear without coming down from the right hand top corner. I have always used the same method of showing alert views and never had animation issues before in my views. I will attach a link to the gif below. I will also add the code for the view.

GIF:

> https://imgflip.com/gif/x61vg

Track1.h

```
//
//  Track1.h
//  uDropOff 3
//
//  Created by Curtis Boylan on 06/01/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Curtis Boylan. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@interface Track1 : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

- (IBAction)back;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *trackingnumber;
- (IBAction)track;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewObject;



@end
```

Track1.m

```
//
//  Track1.m
//  uDropOff 3
//
//  Created by Curtis Boylan on 06/01/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Curtis Boylan. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Track1.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@interface Track1 ()

@end

@implementation Track1
{
    NSMutableArray *tableAray;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableAray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"test",@"test2", nil];

    // [self webstuff1];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  //  UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
   // [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   // [self.table addSubview:refreshControl];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (IBAction)back {
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
- (IBAction)track {
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // saving an NSString
    [prefs setObject:self.trackingnumber.text forKey:@"uDropOffTracking"];
    Track1 *track2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"track2"];
    [self presentViewController:track2 animated:NO completion:nil];

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    return [tableAray count];

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    return 70;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";



    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)

    {

        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    cell.tracking.text = [tableAray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];





    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    UIAlertView *selectedAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]

                                  initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Selected", [tableAray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"It takes 20 mins to prepare!"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Got It" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [selectedAlert show];

}
@end
```

Thanks!

Comment: hey, very interesting problem, i never seen this animation, and a can't  repeat this bug, but first of all, if u realy want to use this alert U should set delegate to self, and U catch this bug on simulator or on real device?

Comment: Hi Joe, I had the error on both real device and the simulator. There was an answer posted below which was part of the solution, the other part was I was using an animation to load the view which was carrying through into the view, so by getting rid of that it fixed all the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, along with Vu's answer I done the following in my other view which was displaying track1.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"track1"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];}
```

Changing it to the following and along with the solution Vu had fixed my issues:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"track1"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:NULL];}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you use

```
[UIView beginAnimations: context:];
```

somewhere in your code?

Make sure call

```
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

right after setting animation option.

Comment: I don't use it anywhere in that view no. I do use it in another view though and I have the commit animations inserted. I will go back over all the view codes and double check that.

Comment: Checked every view, all the code. Added in [UIView commitAnimations]; where it was missing in some views, still with the same issue.